# How can I reuse partials in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a table where each row will be represented by a directive element.
For most rows the same general directive can be used, but a couple of rows will have very specialized information forcing me create specific directives.

A row in my table will look something like this (but with more info per cell):
| Name | Capabilities | Special Info/Functions | General Functions |

I've considered using ng-Include in the different directive-templates like this:

```
<tr><td ng-include="'name.html'"></td><td ng-include="'capablilites.html'"></td>
<td ng-include="'specialX.html'"></td><td ng-include="'general.html'"></td></tr>
```

But the ng-include directive creates a new scope, which I could do without.
What is the smartest and DRYest way of doing this? All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Can't you have a single directive with a dynamic template?

Comment: Maybe a directive which takes an object that represents each `td`, and then populates the template (as @Shaun mentioned) based on the data passed in... `<specialized-info info="currentrow.info"></specialized-info>` ?

Comment: Did you get this working, was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I eventually chose to solve this was with a base-directive which contained the a standard template and a controller with all standard functions.

I configured the base-directive to transclude content and append it at a spesific element (the td that could contain specialized information).

I created a couple of extension-directives that would contained their own specialized templates with buttons, input-fields or just text.
In addition to the partials, the extensions also (in most cases) contained their own controllers which could make changes to the base-directive scope (both overwriting methods and changing variables).

I decided to use a custom transclude function in the base-directive link instead of going with the ng-transclude directive. This allowed the directives to actually share scope instead of just having a reference through $scope.$parent (spared me of some headache).

In the end my directives ended up looking pretty simple and DRY and could be instatiated with a simple:

```
<tr my-base-directive><my-extension></my-extension></tr>
```

My frustration relieving link function:

```
link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl, transcludeFn) {
    transcludeFn( scope, function( clone ) {
        el.find('.append').append( clone );
    });
}
```

PS: If anyone feel cheated of "correct answer", my requirements grew a bit during development (as they always do) and became more clear after posting the question.

Answer (score 1):

**html**

```
<tr ng-repeat="info in ctrl.infocollection">
  <specialized-info info="info"></specialized-info>
</tr>
```

**Directive**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myModule')
        .directive('specializedInfo', specializedInfo);

    function specializedInfo() {

        var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '/app/views/templatename.html',
            scope: {
                info: '=' //use @ in one way
            },
            controller : infoCtrl,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindToController: true     

        };
        return directive;
    }


    function infoCtrl() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.properties....

        //some logic for template
     }
})();
```

In the directive controller, you can set the template properties based on the info being passed in and bind appropriately.

Comment: Ended up using a variation of this theme.
Only some of my rows required the specialized info. Kept these separate from the ng-repeat.
Using a transcluded directive (with replace: true to avoid pesky browser rules regarding tables) helped me avoid repeating partials, and having its own controller with access to scope-variables on parent-scope turned out to be necessary as well valuable.

Answer (score 1):

I used [ngBindHTML](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) and [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) to achieve that.

The view :

```
<tr><td ng-bind-html="nameTemplate"></td><td ng-bind-html="capabilitesTemplate"></td>
<td ng-bind-html="specialTemplate"></td><td ng-bind-html="generalTemplate"></td></tr>
```

The controller :

```
...
$scope.nameTemplate = $sanitize($templateCache.get('name.html'));
...
```

You may need to sanitize your HTML before you bind it to the view, that's why I used it.